# What is mk:@MSITStore?

Tags: windows-7, hyperlink, chm

I have a chm file of the Book [Java and XML, 3rd Edition](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/xml/059610149x) and a section looks like this:

> With the DOMSerializer class complete, all that's left is to invoke
>   the serializer's serialize( ) method in the test class. To do this,
>   add the following lines to the SerializeTester class:
>
> // code here
>
> I ran this program on a couple of files, most notably an XML version
>   of the DOM Level 3 Load and Save module specification
>   (http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-LS-20040407/xml-source.xml).

The link http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-LS-20040407/xml-source.xml was linked to

```
mk:@MSITStore:D:\Desktop\McLaughlin%20-%20Java%20and%20XML%203e%20(O'Reilly,%202006).chm::/059610149X/(http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-LS-20040407/xml-source.xml
```

which obviously gives me:

[image]

What is `mk:@MSITStore`? What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mk:@MSITStore` is an [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme), according to

- [KB235226 - INFO: HTML Help URL Protocols](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235226) <sup>[*archive*](https://archive.ph/5tvtg)</sup>
- [KB896358 - MS05-026: A vulnerability in HTML Help could allow remote code execution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896358%3C/sub%3E) <sup>[*archive*](https://archive.ph/QpgYt)</sup>

and is used in Windows help files as the **"InfoTech"** protocol handler:

> The following is a list of correct HTML Help URLs:
>
> - **Filename.chm::/page.htm** - Only works inside of HTML Help. Microsoft strongly discourages its use (also known as "super-automagic" URL).
> - **Mk:@MSITStore:filename.chm::/page.htm** - The standard HTML Help URL that works with Internet Explorer 3.0 and later (also known as "automagic" URL).
> - **Ms-its:filename.chm::/page.htm** - The new standard HTML Help URL that works with Internet Explorer 4.0 and later (also know as "automagic" URL).

It is used similarly to, let's say, an `http` link. Help files, which are just HTML pages, are compiled into one CHM file. When doing so, pointers to those internally compiled HTML files use the `MSITStore` URI scheme.

For example, this link would point to a general copyright page:

```
mk:@MSITStore:%windir%\Help\ntshared.chm::/copyright.htm
```

This can also be done using other protocol handlers, as explained here: [Using a URL to Open a Page in a Compiled HTML Help File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164814%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

It seems that in your case, the CHM file was improperly generated.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help =D Btw if I understand it correctly, is it true to say that this is purely a microsoft thing?

Comment: Yes. Haven't seen it anywhere else.

Comment: @@slhck ok cool =)